# Take Set-Cookie from incoming message and place in Cookie in outgoing message

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-2016

I have a scenario where I receive a request, and based on that request I have to do a few web service calls to a backend system. All is done in an orchestration. The backend system is session based, so first I perform a login and then I want to do my stuff. The login operation replies with a Set-Cookie header, I want to place that value in the Cookie header in the subsequent calls. However, when trying to do this in a Message assignment shape:

```
msg_request2(HTTP.HttpCookie) = msg_loginresponse(HTTP.HttpCookie)
```

I get an error in the event viewer:

```
Inner exception: There is no value associated with the property 'HTTP.HttpCookie' in the message. 
Exception type: MissingPropertyException 
Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine
```

I've also tried accessing the HTTP.InboundHttpHeaders of msg_loginresponse, same error message. I can see the InboundHttpHeaders context property in the suspended message that results, so i "know" that it's there.

Adding a reference to Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll in my project did not help.

Any clever suggestions?

Comment: First, does it really have to work that way?  Cookies for API apps are almost non-existent these days.  Are you sure they haven't updated to a better solution?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm sure. I wish I could just send an auth token of some sort in my calls, but as it stands, I have to do the login and then copy the cookie to all subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

After you have informed your management that the Trading Partner is using a very old and unusual pattern for which you are going to have to spend extra time, meaning money, to accommodate (this problem is 100% created by the Trading Partner), it should be pretty simple.

For the Adapter, Set-Cookie does not result in an actual cookie since the Adapter has no notion of sessions.

You need to parse the cookie value out of HTTP.InboundHttpHeaders, then use that value to set the cookie by either HTTP.HttpCookie or HTTP.UserHttpHeaders.

BTW, since token auth in 99.9% of scenarios is silly and unnecessary, I always avoid maintaining the token and just 'auth' every time.  No reason for you to make you app more complicated.  The only exception would be if the same calls are performed in the same sequence every time, then you can hold the token in the Orchestration.